# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in celery container while exists in django application container

Tags: django, docker, docker-compose, celery

I am developing a django application in which I have to manipulate excel files. I have two containers: one for my main django application and another for celery where I process my files. These two containers have the same context and share the same environment variables.

here is the view where is my problem:

```
def file_recovery(request):
    reponse = {}
    request.method == "POST":
        extensions = ["xls","xlsx"]
        form = UploadExcelMeterFile(request.POST,request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            excel_file = request.FILES["excel_file"]
            extension = request.FILES["excel_file"].name.split(".")[-1]
            if not extension in extensions:
                ...
            else:
                obj_file = XSLFileObjects.objects.create(file=excel_file) # I create an file objects
                my_task.apply_async(args=[obj_file.id]) # I send the id of that objects to my task to get the file directory
                ...
        else:
            ...
    else:
        ...
```

in my_task.py

```
@shared_task
def ajouter_compteur_depuis_excel(id):
    from elec_meter.models import XLSFileObject
    obj_file = XLSFileObject.objects.get(id=id)
    file = obj_file.file
    ...
```

In my task I try to recover the file and do the processing. This file exists in the django app container but does not exist in celery. I receive `FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` 
When I try to create another object, I notice that the previous file which does not exist appears in celery.
docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services:
  app:
    container_name: ozangue
    build:
      context: .
    command: >
      python manage.py makemigrations --noinput &&
      python manage.py migrate --noinput && 
      python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000"
    ports:
      - 8000:8000
    volumes:
      - ./electron:/electron
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=devsecretkey
      - DEBUG=1
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=ozanguedb
      - DB_USER=ozangue
      - DB_PASS=ozanguedb@2022
      - CELERY_BROKER=redis://redis:6379/0
      - CELERY_BACKEND=redis://redis:6379/0
    depends_on:
      - db
      - redis
  celery:
    container_name: celery-worker
    restart: always
    build:
      context: .
    command: celery -A electron worker -l info #inDEBUGfo
    environment:
      - SECRET_KEY=devsecretkey
      - DEBUG=1
      - DB_HOST=db
      - DB_NAME=ozanguedb
      - DB_USER=ozangue
      - DB_PASS=ozanguedb@2022
    depends_on:
      - app
      - redis
```

Need help please